# React - should i use getDerivedStateFromProps()?

Tags: reactjs

I have read some posts about this function and i'm still confused.

Let's say i have a component called `Index` that renders items based on its own state, after it fetched those items from an API and stored them in its state.

Then, i have a component called `Search` which also fetches items from an API, but then it passes them as `props` to `Index` so `Index` could display them.

How should i update `Index`'s state according to the newly received items from `Search`? Should i only use `getDerivedStateFromProps()`? Should i be using `componentDidUpdate()` as well?

Comment: You don't have to put the props passed down to `Index` from `Search` if it is enough for you to just use the props.

Comment: I do need them to modify `Index`'s state which is what the `render()` function of `Index` uses.

Comment: You can't use `this.props` in `Index`'s render method? You should not put props in state unless you absolutely have to, since it's easy to introduce subtle bugs that way.

Comment: So as a best practice - should i just make `Index` the child of `Search` and have `Search` make that initial API call and then pass the data to `Index`'s constructor where it will receive the fetched data as props?

Comment: It's hard to say for every use case, but if you want to use the props passed in to the component, and you want the rendering to change when the props change, you can just use the props directly instead of copy/pasting them as is to the state. It's just very meaningless to do so.

Comment: Ok makes sense, thanks!